# android application crashes if no internet

Tags: android, crash

I am using this code to check the network availability for the android application.

```
public boolean isOnline(Context ctx) {
        ConnectivityManager conMgr =  (ConnectivityManager)ctx.getSystemService(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE);

        NetworkInfo i = conMgr.getActiveNetworkInfo();
          if (i == null)
            return false;
          if (!i.isConnected())
            return false;
          if (!i.isAvailable())
            return false;
          return true;
    }
```

But if am connect to a WiFi network but no internet is accessible in that network then how I will check that internet is not available, actually my application crashes and I want to show alert box instead of crashing the application!

Does somebody know how to check internet availability?

This is error log:

http://licrp.dnsalias.net:8000/iteam/images/error.jpg

Comment: What's the error in your log?

Comment: pleas see the error log now! it is something happens because of location listener class

Comment: i am just afraid that my application will crash if there is no access to internet! :( i need solution for this!

Comment: Stack Traces are very revealing if you look into what they are trying to tell you.  So what happens at line 192 of your mainLBS.java file?  Is that the code you have posted?  In which case, which line is 192?  The code at that line is trying to reference a Null object.

Comment: Either ctx or conMgr is null.  You can figure it out from the source line or by adding an explicit check.

Comment: The error is actually in the `onLocationChanged()` method, which you didn't post.

Answer (score 0):

If you just want to be sure that you are connected to wifi and have an internet connection you could just ping a known adress, for example google which is usually online :)

```
URL url = new URL("http://www.google.com");
HttpURLConnection conn= (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
int responseCode = conn.getResponseCode();
//if responseCode = 200 - THEn CONN is connected
```